# How can I integrate a dynamic countdown counter which gets the date value from a custom field in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, countdown, custom-fields

I have a concert event page which has a concert start date and time.

I'm trying to place a countdown counter on the page which dynamically displays a countdown for each concert's start date/time

**Platform:** Wordpress 
and I'm pulling a custom field called 'start_date_time'

**Date/time format:** M d yy hh:ss AM or PM

*Example: Apr 26 2016 12:01 AM*

Here is the simple php code I'm using to display the date:

```
<?php 
$eventstart = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'start_date_time', true); 
    echo $eventstart; 
?>
```

My attempts have thus far not been successful, any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you attempted thus far? Many ways you could go with this, probably better for you to post what you've got and what you're having difficulty with.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a countdown timer plugin or if you want to have this done manually then i think this is how it may be done

1) you can capture the custom field data then you can have the current time subtracted from the event date by converting them into seconds

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2016-12-08 16:12:12");
$now = new DateTime();

$difference_in_seconds = $date1->format('U') - $now->format('U');
```

3) once you have the difference then you may convert this back into date time format

```
$createdate = date('H:i:s',$numberofsecs);
```

4) you can use Javascript setInterval() to have this timer run at specified intervals

something like the below snippet

```
<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}
</script>
```

NOTE:- this is what I feel should be the steps to solve but I have not tried the solution myself.

Hope this helps

Take care and Happy coding